# Simplest D3.js example not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this in my `index.html` file but it does not show the paragraph that I want to add with `D3`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> D3 page template </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "d3/d3.v3.js"></script> 
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        d3.select("body").append("p").text("new paragraph!");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The path to where I am referencing `D3.js` should be correct because if I do an inspect element in the browser I can click on the `D3` link and it takes me to its source code.

[image]

Comment: Use http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js in src for d3

Comment: also attached the picture of the error I get.

Comment: @PrasathK : hmm yeah it worked with directly referencing it from the web site but WHY the local one is not working?

Comment: You might have referenced wrongly

Comment: but when I click on it in debugger, it does go to its source code.

Comment: Don't know then ....!!!

Comment: Look to the right of the line that says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL". It says where is this error, which is preventing d3 from loading.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are missing the character set in your HTML page. Add something like this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

The un-minified source of D3 includes the actual symbol for pi, which confuses the browser if the character set is not defined.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Maybe it's a stealth campaign by @mbostock to get people to learn about Unicode and Character Sets :-)

Comment: +1 Very Nice Catch!  I, too, was wondering why I got an error running off the un-minified code and the min code was fine.

Answer (score 7):

I am going to assume that you are testing this out without a web server. If so, then your URL will read  file://.... not http://..

With this, the Javascript request will go to file:///.../D3/d3/d3.v3.js which won't have the proper response header set, such as charset and MIME.

You can always get it from a CDN to avoid this problem:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me. for me I have the below in my file but didn't worked,                <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8"><script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js">    </script>  After, i added charset with cdn, it worked. Why it needed there?

Answer (score 1):

Was having similar issue. My problem was my script file was loading before it could load the d3js library. Just adding `defer` fixed the issue.

`<script src="app.js" defer></script>`

Comment: I suggest adding the line '''<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>'''  Before this one or a reference to the d3 library for better clarity.